# Rxjs: how to observe HTTP response to the last issued Ajax request

Tags: ajax, rxjs

I have a use case of a "quick search' box where the user types first few letters of the search criteria, and the system shows the list of results in real time. E.g. if  you type "J" in a box for the country name, it would show "Jamaica, Japan, Jordan". When you proceed to type "Ja", it would show just Jamaica and Japan, and leave Jordan out.

Each search request is an AJAX call. The trouble with AJAX calls is that the responses may not come in the same order as requests. E.g., the following sequence of events is possible:

1. Request search results for "J".
2. Request search results for "Ja".
3. Receive response to request #2: [Jamaica, Japan]
4. Receive response to request #1: [Jamaica, Japan, Jordan]

If the system blindly shows the last response, it will end up in an inconsistent state, when the search box contains "Ja", but "Jordan" is on the suggestion list. The system should be smart and discard response #4, since it is no longer relevant.

**Does RxJS provide a clean way to discard responses to anything but the last issued request?**

Keep in mind that "last request" changes over time as new requests are produced. I searched the documentation and did not find much. Most tutorials simply ignore this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## &tldr;

You want `switchMap` instead of `flatMap` or `mergeMap`

### Breakdown

I just did a quick google search for "rxjs smart search" and found two of the first two hits dealt with the problem, [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html) and [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/examples/autocomplete).

But for future readers the answer is to use `switchMap` or `flatMapLatest` as it used to be called. As the name would imply, it both switches *and* maps. What does that mean, well from the docs [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-switchMap) it,

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, emitting values only from the most recently projected Observable.

In plain terms, like `flatMap` each single event passed into the callback function of `switchMap` should result in a stream (or stream-like thing). The result of a new emission is that only results from the latest stream are listened to while there is a "best-effort" cancellation made on the original. This happens for each new emission. By best effort it means that if there is a way to halt progress on the stale stream it will be halted, but for some data structures (read: `Promises`) there is no way to actually cancel it once it is in progress so the best the library can do is simply ignore the result.

Comment: Thank you! AutoComplete example looks very promising. If I only knew this is called "smart search"... :) BTW, I think <code>flatMapLatest</code> was a better name.

Comment: As a bonus question, is there a way to only reject the responses that come out of order, i.e. when a response to a later (but not necessarily the latest) request has already been seen? This may be a better strategy for slow requests. E.g. the autocomplete example debounces user input at 750ms. If requests take 800ms to process, I suspect that the user will not see anything at all until he finishes typing, even though the responses do come back. Delayed response is better than no response.

Comment: Marking answer as accepted, but a word of caution here: I have just verified that if one of the "latest" HTTP requests returns an error, the whole process stops and no further inputs will be processed. If a response to a not latest request generates an error, the process continues, making the whole thing rather unpredictable in case of random server errors caused by timeouts or bad connection.

Comment: Yes you are still responsible for error handling in these cases. I would suggest that if you want to make sure your top-level stream stays alive that you put a `catch` operator on the inner ajax call to handle errors.